# AWS Windows EC2 run Selenium Webdriver in foreground

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, selenium-grid

Need Help. Using cloud formation template, I created a windows ec2 instance which runs selenium agent with ie11. However, my power-shell script (triggered using cf template) runs the selenium grid stand alone jar in background. So when the Selenium Grid hub triggers a test, they are also run on ie in background. Issue is some of my tests capture screenshots and they are being returned as black screen.

When selenium grid is run in foreground, I get proper screenshots. How to resolve this issue without RDP into windows machine?

Comment: Issue is resolved. Selenium jar is run from GPO at startup

Comment: can you explain how you did it from commandline?

Comment: 1. Create selenium start up script in a bat file. 
2. Create scripts.ini which can trigger this bat file. 
3. Copy the scripts.ini to startup folder.
4. Create necessary registry variables in Group Policy to run above bat file at startup
5. Reboot the machine